# Hide selected by anchor's href

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor

I'm trying to figure out a function that will allow me to hide `divs` and show them if referring link is clicked.

Hard to explain but here is what I am looking for:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="#id-1">Link 1</a></li>
   <li class="active"><a href="#id-2">Link 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#id-3">Link 1</a></li>
<ul>
<div id="id-1">Some content</div> // Hidden
<div id="id-2">Some content</div> //  This should only show in document
<div id="id-3">Some content</div> // hidden
```

Whenever other anchor is being clicked other `divs` should hide.

I hope his make sense and thank you for your help in advance

Dom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this (untested so may need tweaking):

```
$(document).ready(function() {              //fires on dom ready

    $("a").click(function(e) {              //assign click handler to all <a> tags

        $(".classForYourDivs").hide();      //hide all divs (put class on ones you want to hide)

        var element = $(e.target);
        var href = element.attr("href");    //get the attribute

        $(href).show();                     //show the relevent one
        return false;                       //important to stop default click behavior of link
    });

});
```

Incidentally you should consider using something other than the href to store this information... take a look at the docs for the jquery data() function

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$("a").click( function( ) {
    var elId = $(this).attr("href");
    $(elId).show().siblings("div[id^=id-]").hide();
});
```

Fiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/MPZqT/)

Comment: works as long as there are no other sibling divs, which isn't clear from the markup provided - maybe include an attribute selector along with the div would be more selective?

Comment: you should not do `.replace("#")`, you need `#` for the selector in next line to work

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to the `ul` and the `divs`.

```
<ul class="myUL">
   <li><a href="#id-1">Link 1</a></li>
   <li class="active"><a href="#id-2">Link 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#id-3">Link 1</a></li>
<ul>
<div id="id-1" class="myDivs">Some content</div> // Hidden
<div id="id-2" class="myDivs">Some content</div> //  This should only show in document
<div id="id-3" class="myDivs">Some content</div> // hidden
```

then in CSS,

```
.myDivs { display: none; }
```

and Try below js code,

```
var $myDivs = $('.myDivs');
$('.myUL a').on('click', function () {
    $myDivs.hide();
    $($(this).attr('href')).show();
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/LYKVG/

Answer (score 1):

```
$("body").on("click","a", function(){
    var divtoshowselector = $(this).attr("href");
    $(divtoshowselector).show().siblings().hide();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/

### html

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="#id-1">Link 1</a></li>
   <li class="active"><a href="#id-2">Link 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#id-3">Link 3</a></li>
<ul>
<div id="id-1">Some content 1</div> 
<div id="id-2">Some content 2</div>
<div id="id-3">Some content 3</div>​
```

### css

```
div {display: none;}
```

### javascript/jquery

```
$("a").click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();    
    var elId = $(this).attr('href');
    $('div').hide();
    $(elId).show();
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

I've set up a fiddle for you, check out: http://jsfiddle.net/UsGag/

```
function currentActive()
{
    return $("li.active a").attr("href");
}

$("div:not(" + currentActive() + ")").hide();

$("li a").on("click", function()
{
    //hide old active div
    $("div" + currentActive()).hide();
    $("li").removeClass("active");

    //activate new div
    $(this).parent().addClass("active");    
    $("div" + currentActive()).show();
});
```

Hope this helps you, extend to your own needs. And just for completeness: Don't use the `-` in ids / classnames.
​